# JScrollPane isn't working in GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout, user-interface, jscrollpane

OK, I am trying to create a GUI that has a JScrollPane that, through the JTextArea, will print out an array of ints, one line at a time. I am using some methods I created for an assignment to deal with the data, and have one of them working on the data in the following example, (I can't show the methods because it's homework that isn't due yet). The methods have been tested and work fine, so no need for them in this question. So far, either the text area will show up in the GUI, but not have the scroll pane attached to it, or only the jlabel will show up with the results of the work done via the method. Can someone have a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong, because I have gone over this like 50 times, and cannot get the GUI to behave.

```
public class MyClassName extends JFrame{

private JScrollPane myScroll;
private JTextArea myTextArea;
private JLabel myMean;
private JLabel myMedian;
private JLabel myMax;
private JLabel myMin;
private JLabel mySum;
private Container content;
private Font myFont;
private SpringLayout layout;


private MyClassName() {
    this(500,300,"TEST TITLE");
}

private MyClassName(int width, int height, String title)
{
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setSize(width, height);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    guiComponent();
}

public void guiComponent()
{
    layout = new SpringLayout();
    content = this.getContentPane();

    int [] test = {50,37,43,12,8,16,32,44,78,92,1,3,66,34};

    myTextArea = new JTextArea();

    myScroll = new JScrollPane(myTextArea);
    content.add(myScroll);

    myMean = new JLabel("MEAN : " + MyClassName.mean(test));
    for(int count : test)
    {
        String z = Integer.toString(count);
        myTextArea.append('\n' + z);
    }

    myFont = new Font("Serrif", Font.BOLD, 30);
    myMean.setFont(myFont);

    content.add(myScroll);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, myScroll, 20, SpringLayout.WEST, content);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, myScroll, 25, SpringLayout.NORTH, content);

    content.add(myMean);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, myMean, 20, SpringLayout.EAST, myScroll);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, myMean, 25, SpringLayout.NORTH, content);
}

public static double mean(int[] ar) {
    double x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        x += ar[i];
    }
    return x / ar.length;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClassName test2 = new MyClassName();
}
```

Comment: Consider adding a `public static void main(String args[])` to be a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) so people can copy paste and test your code..

Comment: I added the main, and also the 1 method I am using in this example

Comment: OK, so I restarted netbeans, and now it the text area and scrollpane pop up in the GUI, but they take up the whole GUI, even when I add a size parameter to the text area, and the jlabel, which should be to the right of the text area, still isn't there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem when you need to display the components in layout, to solve your problem add those three line after initialize 'myTextArea' component:

```
myTextArea.setColumns(20);
myTextArea.setRows(5);
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
```

you maybe need to read this [link about Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).

Comment: Awesome! That fixed the scrollPanel problem at least. The JLabel still doesn't pop up beside it unless you grab a corner of the GUI window and move it, any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Actually, I read the info at the link you gave me, and just used .isVisible(); and now it shows, so thanks again!

Comment: Actually, no, that didn't work either, the jlabel only pops up the first time you run the program, after that, it just seems to disappear, which is really strange

Comment: i see now your update in your code with main method, but you can move the `setVisible(true);` to the default contractor or replace the line of initial test2 variable to this line `new MyClassName().setVisible(true);`

Comment: Putting this.setVisible(true); inside my guiComponent method fixed it, thanks. I had it there originally, but moved it when I was trying to sort out the problem earlier.